# Writing to Xamarin Pre-populated Database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, xamarin

I followed this tutorial to set up a pre-populated database for my mobile app:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQtNynTLhl4&ab_channel=kc70

It works as intended and I'm now able to pull and display data from the database that I've added to my project as an embedded resource. The only issue is I'm unable to write to the database. Whenever I do an insert or update to one of the tables the database doesn't store the new data.

How can I fix this?

```
public App()
{
            InitializeComponent();

            string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "myDatabase.db3");

            Assembly assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
            Stream embeddedDbStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.myDatabase.db3");
           
            FileStream fileStreamToWrite = File.Create(dbPath);
            embeddedDbStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            embeddedDbStream.CopyTo(fileStreamToWrite);
            fileStreamToWrite.Close();
}
```

Comment: I've done that. Pulling data down through SELECT statements works fine. I don't understand why an INSERT won't work

Comment: the code you have will run EVERY time you start the app and overwrite the file at `dbpath`.  You need to check if the file exists and write ONLY if it does not.

Comment: @Jason That's a good point, but even after adding `if (!File.Exists(dbPath))` the issue persists. After doing some more research it appears you cannot write to an Embedded Resource. How can I get around this?

Comment: you can't write to an embedded resource, but you are copying the resource to a file in a writable folder so that should not be an issue.  You are using `dbpath` as the path for your DB connection, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: ou could use the plugin sqlite-net-pcl .Check  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases